# Affectiva not starting Web Cam on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, webcam, affdex-sdk

I'm trying to use Affectiva's Web SDK (Javascript) to detect emotions via a Camera Stream. I tried using it in JS Fiddle. It works fine but when I got the code from JSFiddle and used in on my Java Web Project in Eclipse, the Web Camera prompt isn't showing up. Nor can it access the Web Cam. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8" id="affdex_elements"   style="width:680px;height:480px;"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div style="height:25em;">
          <strong>EMOTION TRACKING RESULTS</strong>
          <div id="results" style="word-wrap:break-word;"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <strong>DETECTOR LOG MSGS</strong>
        </div>
        <div id="logs"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="start" onclick="onStart()">Start</button>
      <button id="stop" onclick="onStop()">Stop</button>
      <button id="reset" onclick="onReset()">Reset</button>
      <h3>Affectiva JS SDK CameraDetector to track different emotions.</h3>
      <p>
        <strong>Instructions</strong>
        </br>
        Press the start button to start the detector.
        <br/> When a face is detected, the probabilities of the different emotions are written to the DOM.
        <br/> Press the stop button to end the detector.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The Javascript file is similar to the contents in https://jsfiddle.net/affectiva/opyh5e8d/show/

I copied the code but the camera doesn't work on my end when I used it on Eclipse. I'm using Chrome as my browser.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on the developer-portal (http://developer.affectiva.com/v3_1/javascript/analyze-camera/) ?

Comment: How are you loading the JS?